# I'm getting error 404 while trying to access my spring boot app on Amazon Elastic Bean Stalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, war, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I developed a `spring boot` application and I've put the following entries in `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
server.port=5000
```

Now when I start it (`mvn clean spring-boot:run`) locally, I'm getting the output `Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http)` and the app is accessible in the browser under http://localhost:5000/welcome .

I created a `Java` instance in Amazon Elastic Bean Stalk, I've uploaded `war`, I even opened the port 5000 in the corresponding Security Group on EC2 instance:

[image]

but when I now go to http://my-aws-ebs-instance.com/welcome:5000, I'm getting the following message:

[image]

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Dec 20 16:30:33 UTC 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). /welcome.jsp

Why oh why does it happen like this? What did I forget to configure?

----EDIT

as requested, here's the root java class:

```
package com.hellokoding.auth;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is also the structure of my project with highlighted `welcome.jsp` page:

[image]

When I unzip the generated `war` file, this is the file structure on my hard drive:

[image]

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <name>auth</name>
    <description>my descr</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the `UserController` class contains:

```
...

@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(Model model) {

    return "welcome";
}

...
```

I added some logs inside the `welcome` method and I see it is running correctly. Also, in log files I can see the following entry:

```
Mapped "{[/ || /welcome],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hellokoding.auth.web.UserController.welcome(org.springframework.ui.Model)
```

so I have no idea why this thing does not work. After trying for 11 hours straight to make it work I'm questioning my life choices, and also I'm wondering why anyone would ever use such a stupid framework since it doesn't work ootb.

--- edit:

I've uploaded a simplified code to github https://github.com/nalogowiec/springbootProblem

Comment: can you post your Root Java Class @SpringBootApplication?

Comment: @slimane I added it to the original question

Comment: tomcat is clearly listening to your requests, but it couldn't route them, can you try spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/

Comment: @slimane I'm not sure about the `/WEB-INF`, but I just updated the question with the project structure, could you please take a look? maybe I should add there some other path then?

Comment: I'm not sure if this should work when packaging as war file, can you try moving your welcome.jsp into the root inside webapp (just for debugging your problem)

Comment: well so it's kind of weird on the screenshot, but `welcome.jsp` apparently is in the webapp directly, not in resources :)

Comment: btw @slimane what if I change the packaging in pom.xml to jar, do you think that would be enough?

Comment: `http://my-aws-ebs-instance.com/welcome:5000` this is invalid url. Please paste actual URL you are trying to access instead of creating bunch of rubbish and misleading informations.

Comment: Add `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` to app properties and see the actuall error.

Comment: replace @SpringBootApplication with  @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.hellokoding.auth.web", "com.hellokoding.auth.model"}) and  clean your project and restart it.

Comment: @Antoniossss I added `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`, but then I'm getting just a plain 404 page in my browser

Comment: @DipakThoke unfortunately this also didn't help, nothing has changed, the issue still occurs

Comment: I just checked and my JS script that normally is stored in `/resources/js/script.js` is accessible via browser on `http://my-aws-ebs-instance.com:5000/js/script.js`

Comment: @randomuser1 can you please upload your project to github and share the link here will help you...

Comment: @DipakThoke https://github.com/nalogowiec/springbootProblem here is the github link, thank you very much for helping me out

Comment: You may not be properly configuring Beanstalk health check URL. Are you mapping to /actuator/health?

Comment: One thing to be clear about, you can skip using WAR files with Spring Boot. The plugin automatically can generate a fat jar with all the dependencies.Can you please generate the fat jar and execute a `java -jar yourjar.jar` locally to see if everything works? Then trigger the app and see if it returns the correct result.

Comment: @galovics good catch, when I ran it with `java -jar myjar.jar` the result is the same as in the question - I'm getting the same whitelist error! So now at least we know it's not the problem related to AWS...

Comment: I think your problem is from your dependencies, can you remove this one spring-boot-starter-tomcat and also remove <scope>provided</scope> from tomcat-embed-jasper?

Comment: @slimane unfortunately that also didn't help, you can try to test it out on my github code https://github.com/nalogowiec/springbootProblem - when I build the jar and then run it `java -jar myjar.jar`, I'm still seeing the well known 404 error in the browser under `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: I just downloaded the sample code from here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/ and when I run it as `war` locally - it works! but when I upload it to this beanstack sh*t - then it does not and the 404 error persists. I will have an awful christmas because of this STUPID problem

Comment: yes I got that too, can you remove what I said above and don't extend extends SpringBootServletInitializer, this works for me locally, can you test also it on elb?

Comment: @randomuser1 sorry for late response but i have solved your problem.please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

**If you want Spring Boot With JSPs in Executable Jars**

Keep in mind that we will ultimately place the JSP templates under `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/`

**Note :**
define the template prefix and suffix for our JSP files in application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Then your can run jar file using below command :

```
java -jar <your jar name>

 for your project you can below command

   java -jar  auth-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar
```

For More reference : https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1

**Solution 2:**

**JSP Limitations**

When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some limitations in the JSP support.

With Jetty and Tomcat, it should work if you use war packaging. An executable war will work when launched with java -jar, and will also be deployable to any standard container. JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar.
Undertow does not support JSPs.
Creating a custom error.jsp page does not override the default view for error handling. Custom error pages should be used instead.

I have clone your GitHub project able to run project(if you follow below steps your problem will get solve definitely)

```
Step To run your project :

Step 1 : Create war package of your project

Step 2 : Run your war package using below command 

    java -jar <your war file name> 

    i.e for your project command should be like :

      java -jar  auth-1.3.5.RELEASE.war

Step 3 : Hit the URL  http://localhost:5000/
```

You can see the result in browser.

More reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: It did solve my problem, thank you very much, the bounty is yours, happy new year man :)

Answer (score 2):

Nice explanation @dipak-thoke.

Just to add if anyone automating the deployment process (In my case, it was through CodeBuild And CodeDeploy), you can create [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-procfile.html) and deploy the war. I have added Procfile into the root directory of the project and added it as an artifact. 
Hope this helps someone looking for same usage case :)

ProcFile:

```
web: java -jar <your_war_file>.war
```

This is how my CodeBuild Buildspec looks like:

```
version: 0.2

phases:

  build:
    commands:
      # - command
      - ./gradlew bootWar
  post_build:
    commands:
      # - command
      - echo Build must be completed
      - mv build/libs/*.war <WarFileName>.war

artifacts:
  files:
    # - location
     - <WarFileName>.war
     - Procfile
  #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  #base-directory: location
#cache:
  #paths:
    # - paths
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Spring Boot docs, its clear that you are using the wrong directory structure.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc

> By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext ... Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application is packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it works only with war packaging, and it is silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.

Comment: I've changed the structure of my project, but that didn't help either, I've updated the code here https://github.com/nalogowiec/springbootProblem is there anything that I could possibly miss here?

Comment: welcome.jsp is still located under webapp instead of resources

Answer (score -1):

Since you have your app on port 5000 it is accessible on that port, not default http port 80.

Either access it with

```
http://my-aws-ebs-instance.com:5000/welcome
```

or create port forwarding rune in AWS so traffing going to port 80 will be pushed you application server's port 5000.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad, of course I'm trying to access it on `http://my-aws-ebs-instance.com:5000/welcome`, the url without port results in 502 error from ngix... Sorry, I edited my question and I added the 5000 port to the url