# Spring Boot Rest Service Running fine on local , but showing 404 after deploying on AWS EBS

Tags: spring-boot

I have created Spring Boot Rest Sample service with one endpoint.

It is running fine on local.

http://localhost:8080/test

I deployed the same on EBS as well with the EBS endpoint.

demomitesh.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

[image: application dashboard]

when i am trying to access the endpoint with the URL

demomitesh.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/test,

I get 404 Below Error.

[image: error page]

Comment: can you plz attach screen shot of project structure will help you...

Comment: your deploying jar or war file??? also share pom.xm file

Comment: Upadhyay  i have already given solution this type problem plz refer below link this solve your problem for sure : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872767/im-getting-error-404-while-trying-to-access-my-spring-boot-app-on-amazon-elasti/53921410#53921410

Comment: is your problem solved??

Comment: Yes. deepak Thanks for your kind support