# Spring boot: resolve JSPs from jar dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

Unfortunately haven't found an answer in official documentation. Maybe what I'm trying to do is not supported event by Tomcat, but still. **Is it possible to make spring-boot/Tomcat to resolve JSP pages from `.jar` file that is in the classpath?**

I have a spring-boot (2) application that is packed as a `war` file. There are a numerous `jsp` pages in 'webapp/view' folder, and appropriate MVC configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class MVCConf implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // ...
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver(){{
            setPrefix("/view/");
            setSuffix(".jsp");
            setRedirectHttp10Compatible(false);
        }};
    }
    // ...
}
```

All these pages are being resolved. Okay.

But. The project is a multi-module maven one. It supports builds with different dependencies (my own modules) depending on maven profiles.

I need to make application to resolve JSPs from those optional dependencies that are included into runtime as `jar`s in a classpath.

And I'm getting Whitelabel error that says that JSP files can not be found.

Is it even possible to make it work? And if it is, than how?

P.S.: I have already tried to make some magic with copying JSPs into "root" spring-boot application itself and it works, but this way is dirty and tricky.

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: @Avijit Barua, I've posted maven-dependency-plugin configuration below. But the final solution is more accurate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872767/im-getting-error-404-while-trying-to-access-my-spring-boot-app-on-amazon-elasti/53921410#53921410 please check this answer

Comment: Well, it's close to my question, but it's not exactly what I asked about. It "reveals" how to resolve JSPs in executable jar. I use a word reveal here because this topic is not covered well in documentation.
But in my case the problem is in resolving JSPs from jars that are included into war as a dependency. 
Nevertheless, thanks for the reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting error 404 while trying to access my spring boot app on Amazon Elastic Bean Stalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872767/im-getting-error-404-while-trying-to-access-my-spring-boot-app-on-amazon-elasti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is worth to publish the whole `pom.xml`, but here is the `maven-dependency-plugin` section that works in my case:

```xml
            <!-- ... -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <!-- this skip property is set by maven profile in same pom.xml - no magic here -->
                            <skip>${exclude.some_submodule}</skip>

                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>some_submodule</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>

                                    <!-- there are webapp/view/*.jsp files in some_module's structure -->
                                    <includes>view/**</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- ... -->
```

The only problem here is that it works only when you launch the executable `.war`. Launching this application from IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) need some additional steps to be made. And that's another one disadvantage of this solution, to my mind. The first one is a dirty `pom.xml`.

**TL;DR**

**Solution:**

**BUT!**. [I have found another solution that is more suitable, I think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013917/can-i-serve-jsps-from-inside-a-jar-in-lib-or-is-there-a-workaround?rq=1). 
Actually I have moved from Tomcat to Jetty, and solution above works fine even there. There's no need in hacking the build anymore.

Now I put my `.jsp` files into `src/main/webapp/META-INF/resources/view/some_module` folder in **some_module** dependency and resolve it by path 'some_module/someJsp' via standard Spring's `@Controller`s.

I apologize that I haven't found this topic earlier. Now this is a duplicate. But who knows, maybe someone will apply solution with maven dependency plugin.